# NoMethodError: undefined method `l1' for #<model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, `Passenger` and `Location`

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :passengers   
end
```

and

```
class Passenger < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :location
end
```

I insert some data in `rails console`

**p1 is passenger record**

```
p1
 => #<Passenger id: 2, name: "Saba", lastname: "las", phone: 1234, created_at: "2015-11-15 13:04:03", updated_at: "2015-11-15 13:04:03", id_location: 1>
```

**and l1 is a location record**

```
l1
 => #<Location id: 1, latitude: 1.4, longitude: 4.5, created_at: "2015-11-15 13:02:00", updated_at: "2015-11-15 13:02:00">
```

"`id_location`" is a foreign key for location in `Passenger`

I did `p1.save` and `l1.save`.

i expect `p1.l1` gives me the complete data including l1 record like(`Location id: 1, latitude: 1.4`)

instead it gives me the following erorr:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `l1' for #<Passenger:0x000000022b96c8>
```

Comment: Please read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `foreign_key` is wrong; Rails default `foreign_keys` are `association_id` (*not* `id_association`, as you have it).

--

To fix it, you'll either need to set the foreign key explicitly (and call the correct associative object), or rename the `id_location` column in your table:

```
#app/models/passenger.rb
class Passenger < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :location, foreign_key: :id_location
end
```

You should also note the [*belongs_to*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) association call -

[image]

With ActiveRecord, if you have the `foreign key` in a model, that model needs to *belong to* another. Using `has_one` suggests you should put the foreign key in the associated model, which is incorrect in this case.

--

Finally, you also need to make sure you're calling the associated objects by the correct name.

If your `Passenger belongs_to Location`, you will need to call `@passenger.location`